# IOS application autoupdates

Tags: ios

Hi i am new to the IOS application development. So in my application i want give an update about my application for example if i add some images or data's it also atomatically update in the user side also i have no idea how to do this.

Can any one please suggest some ideas to make this one.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you mean change in web application automatically update data in ios?

Comment: backgorunding update is not possible in ios(some thing little is supported in ios7).one thing when you open app or refresh page it will automatically update

Comment: something like that manujmv if that possible can u help me hw to do it?

Comment: if in ios7 it possiable how can i do it can pls guide me kamalesh kumar yadav

Answer (score 0):

In iOS7 you can fetch the contents from the server in background. From apple docs:

> iOS 7 supports two new background execution modes for apps:
>
> - Apps that regularly update their content by contacting a server can register with the system and be launched periodically to retrieve that content in the background. To register, include the UIBackgroundModes key with the fetch value in your app’s Info.plist file. Then, when your app is launched, call the setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval: method to determine how often it receives update messages. Finally, you must also implement the application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler: method in your app delegate.
> - Apps that use push notifications to notify the user that new content is available can fetch the content in the background. To support this mode, include the UIBackgroundModes key with the remote-notification value in your app’s Info.plist file. You must also implement the application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: method in your app delegate.
>
> Apps supporting either the fetch or remote-notification background modes may be launched or moved from the suspended to background state at appropriate times.

Comment: hi Anil i think 1st one  looks gud for can pls help how to do that background process or can u suggest any tutorial for the background process because im stuck with this for long time.

Comment: and thanx for everyone who replayed me